# Oracle Tables USER_JOBS and DBA_JOBS consist of duplicate entry

Tags: oracle, materialized-views

I have a Materialized View (MV) which scheduled to refresh daily. Then I drop it and create the same MV which schedule to refresh every two days. But when I execute below sql to check, I saw there were 2 entry with different NEXT_DATE

```
select * from user_jobs WHERE what LIKE 'dbms_refresh.refresh%Schema1%MV_AAAA_S1%';
```

[image: image1]

Hence instead of refresh every two days, the MV still refresh daily. When I drop the MV and execute the above sql to check again, I saw the newly created MV has been removed but the existing still exist

My question is, Why would this happened and how should I remove the existing scheduled of the MV in table USER_JOBS and DBA_JOBS.

Appreciate if anyone could help to advise on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue by remove the duplicated Job with following command

> EXEC DBMS_JOB.REMOVE(383)

Answer (score 0):

These are **two different jobs**. See the `JOB` column? `383` and `227`. Looks like you created two of them so ... that's the result. If you don't need one, drop it.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, I understand that there are 2 different jobs exist. As shared above, I have drop the MV and select again the table USER_JOBS, the job 227 is removed but the job 383 is still there. Both jobs are with same name "Schema1"."MV_AAAA_S1". So I can't drop it twice because it gave me error ORA-12003: materialized view or zonemap "Schema1"."MV_AAAA_S1" does not exist

Comment: Hm. The way I see it is: screenshot shows USER_JOBS. You should drop a **job**, not a **materialized view** to get rid of it. No?

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, noted that I should kill the duplicated job instead of just dropping MV. I am not sure why the duplicated job because I didnt create it and thought it was created associated with the MV creation.
Thanks you for pointing it out

Comment: I told you; it is a job that is duplicated.